# Improve speed of SciPy Pearson correlation for many pairwise calculations?

Tags: python, correlation, scipy.stats

I have a data frame with 1222 rows and 33,000 columns. I need to compute the pairwise correlation coefficients (and associated p-values) between the first 16,000 columns and the remaining columns. Currently, I am using `scipy.stats.pearsonr` like:

```py
from scipy.stats import pearsonr


def correlation_analysis(lncRNA_PC_T):
    """Function for correlation analysis"""
    correlations = pd.DataFrame()
    for PC in [column for column in lncRNA_PC_T.columns if "_PC" in column]:
        for lncRNA in [
            column for column in lncRNA_PC_T.columns if "_lncRNAs" in column
        ]:
            correlations = correlations.append(
                pd.Series(
                    pearsonr(lncRNA_PC_T[PC], lncRNA_PC_T[lncRNA]),
                    index=["PCC", "p-value"],
                    name=PC + "_" + lncRNA,
                )
            )

    return correlations
```

The above code is doing its job; however, for my large data frame, it is taking more than 30 minutes to finish. How can I speed this up?

Comment: append() will typically take longer than pre-allocating space and indexing to add data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried without the append(), however, it still taking long as it used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can speed this up by over three order of magnitude on the CPU and a few additional orders of magnitude with a GPU.

I generated some random data to use and structured it like your DataFrame. The size of the DataFrame is reduced so that your code runs in reasonable time.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(4582345683546)

m = 120
n = 330
nx = 160
ny = n - nx

data = rng.random((m, n))
column_names = ([f'_PC{i}' for i in range(nx)] 
                + [f'_lncRNAs{i}' for i in range(ny)])
lncRNA_PC_T = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
```

The original `correlation_analysis` takes ~75 seconds to run on a regular Colab instance. The NumPy code below takes about 22 milliseconds, and the test at the end confirms that the resulting statistic and p-value arrays are the same as the columns of your DataFrame.

```py
import numpy as xp
from scipy.special import betainc

# import cupy as xp
# from cupyx.scipy.special import betainc

def pearsonr2(x, y):
    # Assumes inputs are DataFrames and computation is to be performed
    # pairwise between columns. We convert to arrays and reshape so calculation
    # is performed according to normal broadcasting rules along the last axis.
    x = xp.asarray(x).T[:, xp.newaxis, :]
    y = xp.asarray(y).T
    n = x.shape[-1]

    # Compute Pearson correlation coefficient. We can't use `cov` or `corrcoef`
    # because they want to compute everything pairwise between rows of a
    # stacked x and y.
    xm = x.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    ym = y.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    cov = xp.sum((x - xm) * (y - ym), axis=-1)/(n-1)
    sx = xp.std(x, ddof=1, axis=-1)
    sy = xp.std(y, ddof=1, axis=-1)
    rho = cov/(sx * sy)

    # Compute the two-sided p-values. See documentation of scipy.stats.pearsonr.
    ab = n/2 - 1
    x = (abs(rho) + 1)/2
    p = 2*(1-betainc(ab, ab, x))
    return rho, p

df_corr = correlation_analysis(lncRNA_PC_T)
%timeit correlation_analysis(lncRNA_PC_T)
# 1min 14s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

x = lncRNA_PC_T.iloc[:, :nx]
y = lncRNA_PC_T.iloc[:, nx:]
corr2, p2 = pearsonr2(x, y)
%timeit pearsonr2(x, y)
# 21.9 ms ± 190 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Check results
np.testing.assert_allclose(corr2.ravel(), df_corr.iloc[:, 0])
np.testing.assert_allclose(p2.ravel(), df_corr.iloc[:, 1])
```

By commenting out the NumPy/SciPy imports and uncommenting the CuPy imports, you can speed things up even more.