# How do you speed up np.corrcoef with numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

My code is simply this:

```
@njit()
def corr(arr: np.ndarray):
    return np.corrcoef(arr)

arr = np.random.random([10000, 10000])
corr_matrix = corr(arr)
```

It takes around 50 seconds to finish on my computer, and just 18 seconds without `@njit`.  If I increase size to 30,000, the function takes forever.

Is there a way to improve performance of numba `@njit` on `np.corrcoef` like in this situation or `np.corrcoef` is already as fast as it can be?  I think I'm not understanding numba correctly here because it's a lot slower with `@njit` than without.

Comment: Have you seen [this github issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4399)?

Comment: @jared: Yes, I saw it.  The issue was posted 4.5 years ago.  I suppose there could be an update or a fix to it now.

Comment: Does it need to be with Numba? I just wrote this about speeding up pairwise correlation coefficient calculations with pure NumPy and optionally CuPy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817623/improve-speed-of-scipy-pearson-correlation-for-many-pairwise-calculations/78025304#78025304

Comment: @ntintel At the moment it is still an open github issue.

Comment: For your use case it might only be faster with CuPy, though. I can't see why `corrcoef` would be slower than what I wrote there with pure NumPy. (The difference there was they had two *different* arrays between which they wanted to take pairwise coefficients, and the alternative was a `for` loop.) And if you can use CuPy, then you can just use `cupy.corrcoef`.

Comment: @Matt.  Thanks Matt.  I will give CuPy a try.  Regarding your other post of rewriting the code, I prefer to use numpy's out of the box implementation for it, unless there is a reason that numpy is not efficient at this job which I'd be surprised if it's not.

Comment: @Jared. Thanks Jared.  Seems like it is.

Comment: Tracing the Numpy code involved, it seems to spend most of its time doing `arr.dot(arr.T)` to calculate covariance. Interestingly, it seems like a function with that and nothing else gets slower when passed through `@njit`. That suprises me - I thought Numba was just calling BLAS to do the matrix multiply, so `@njit` would make no difference.

Comment: @Nick: yeah, maybe numba won't help in this case for now.

Comment: @Matt: I created a new clean project to try CuPy, and the results are computed in 4 seconds for Numpy.corrcoef, 9 seconds for numba on top of numpy, and 14.4 seconds for CuPy.  Numpy is still the winner.

Comment: @MattHaberland Why do you expect CuPy to be faster here? This is a double-precision array so it will ba slower on mainstream GPU (which are not design for that), and only faster on high-end server-side (very expensive) GPUs.

Comment: Because I tested it on Colab T4 and it *is* faster, even with the overhead of transferring data back and forth. I suppose I'll post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, the OP seemed interested in a speedup using a GPU, so I tested CuPy `corrcoef` on a Colab T4 GPU instance.

```py
from time import perf_counter_ns
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(65651651684)
x = rng.random((3000, 3000))

%timeit np.corrcoef(x)
# 835 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit cp.asnumpy(cp.corrcoef(x))  # faster
# 273 ms ± 2.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit cp.asnumpy(cp.corrcoef(x, dtype=cp.float32))  # much faster
# 37.8 ms ± 581 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If we're concerned about the possibility of caching or lazy evaluation, we can generate new data, run once, and even include a `print` statement for good measure.

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(23368551581)
x = rng.random((3000, 3000))

tic = perf_counter_ns()
rho0 = np.corrcoef(x)
print(rho0[0])
toc = perf_counter_ns()
print(toc - tic)  # 879117900

tic = perf_counter_ns()
rho = cp.asnumpy(cp.corrcoef(x))
print(rho[0])
toc = perf_counter_ns()
print(toc - tic)  # 445459866

# passes
np.testing.assert_allclose(cp.asnumpy(rho), rho0)

tic = perf_counter_ns()
rho = cp.asnumpy(cp.corrcoef(x, dtype=cp.float32))
print(rho[0])
toc = perf_counter_ns()
print(toc - tic)  # 41231956

# passes, although it may depend on how nice your data is numerically
np.testing.assert_allclose(cp.asnumpy(rho), rho0, atol=1e-6)
```

I also checked the NumPy calculations on a regular CPU instance with both float64 and float32, and the CuPy calculations on the T4 were faster.

Results may vary by GPU, but I figured this comparison was fair since anyone can use Colab (for some amount of time) for free. I don't know the constraints of the OP, but use of a GPU - especially with `float32` arithmetic - seems to be a way to speed up correlation correctly calculation for large arrays.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Very interesting take, especially with float32.  My use case can accept float16 too.  I bet it will even be exponentially faster.

Comment: I just switched to float32 without changing anything else in the code or platform, and speed was improved by roughly 35%.  Float16, surprisingly, took forever and was eventually terminated.  I think your CuPy solution on Colab could be it.

Comment: Just read somewhere that GPUs and perhaps others are optimized for float 32.

Comment: @ntintel yes, I should have included NumPy `float32` in the comparison for completeness. On Colab, it was about twice as fast as NumPy `float64` and comparable to CuPy `float64`. CuPy `float32` was miles ahead of either one, though.